# Just a simple Javascript function to strengthen the core concept of function call

Tags: javascript

This gives the output of 0 which means that something is wrong with how I call the factorial function.

```
    function factorial(n) {
        let answer = 1;
        if (n === 0 || n === 1) {
            return answer;
        } else {
            for (var i = n; i >= 1; i--) {
                answer = answer * i;
            }
            return answer;
        }
    }
   let computation = 0;

  function compute(){
    let a = 5;
    let b = 6
    let sum = a + b;
    computation = sum + factorial(5);
  }
  console.log(`The value of this is + ${computation}`);
```

Comment: You never call `compute`

Comment: Lol. Missed something as simple as that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see you calling compute (i.e. `compute()`), so `computation` is still as you initialized it as `0`.